# Use TikZ to draw frontpage

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm not that familiar with TikZ and I want to use it for designing by front page. I want a blue bar in the top, where some text is centered in the bar. Like following (how do I center the text without using hspace to push the text in?)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node [xshift=\,yshift=-2cm] at (current page.north west)
  [text width=\textwidth,fill=my_defined_blue,below right]
  {
   \hspace{3.5cm} \textcolor{white}{\Large{\textsc{School Name}}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, I also want a logo on bar, which should be a bit larger than the bar. Any suggestions, how this should be done?

The logo structure:
[image: Logo structure]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? The frame around the logo is drawn "by hand", so if you have a complicated shape, your suggestion of using a transparent PNG with a white border might be more practical.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\coordinate [below=2.5cm] (midpoint) at (current page.north);

\node [name=colourbar,
anchor=base,
fill=blue!40,
text = white,
minimum width=\paperwidth,
minimum height=1cm] at (midpoint) {\huge{\textsc{School Name}}};

% Define the point where the logo will go
\coordinate [right=4cm] (logo) at (colourbar.west);

% Set coordinate system origin
\begin{scope}[shift=(logo)]
% Draw the outline
\filldraw [white,draw=red] (2.3,0.85) -- (-2,0.85) -- (-2.8,-0.85) -- (2.3,-0.85) --cycle;
% Include the logo
\node {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\section{Normal stuff starts here}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: Title page with TikZ]

Comment: Nice! Yes, something like that. I have edited the my post, with the more tricky part of the bar. The logo should is in between the red area. My backup solution to this, is to use a transparent png image in the corner with a white background. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: This example is giving this error l.26 \node {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo}}

Comment: "logo" refers to a file called "logo.png" that needs to be in the same directory as the tex file. I used the [LaTeX logo found on Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/LaTeX_logo.svg/500px-LaTeX_logo.svg.png).