# Title page using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles

Based on the question on [Use TikZ to draw frontpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/use-tikz-to-draw-frontpage/9407#9407), I have taken the liberty to create my own custom LaTeX title template for my school's reports. So far I created this.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,
11pt,
DIV=14,
parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}

%MEDTADATA ,
\def\myauthor{Author} % Author
\def\mycoauthor{} % co-author
\def\mytitle{Title} % titel van het document
\def\mydate{27 Januari 2010} % datum indien gewenst
\def\typedoc{Lab report} %type of document: lab report, article
\def\mycourse{Course Name} % gives the name of the coure

\begin{document}


\begin{titlepage}.
%Use the tikzpicture for the document banner

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\coordinate [below=2.5cm] (midpoint) at (current page.north);

\node [name=colourbar,
anchor=base,
fill=blue!40,
text = white,
minimum width=\paperwidth,
minimum height=1cm] at (midpoint){\Large{\textsf{Departement Industriële Wetenschappen}}};

% Define the point where the logo will go
\coordinate [right=4cm] (logo) at (colourbar.west);

% Set coordinate system origin
\begin{scope}[shift=(logo)]
% Draw the outline
\filldraw [white,draw=blue!40] (2.3,0.85) -- (-2,0.85) -- (-2.8,-0.85) -- (2.3,-0.85) --cycle;
% Include the logo
\node {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{Logo_Lessius_Mechelen_colour.jpg}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{3cm}
\begin{center}
\Huge
\textsf{\mytitle}
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
\vspace{2cm}

%\LARGE
\Large
\textsf{\typedoc\\
\emph{\textcolor{gray}{door}} \\
\myauthor\\
\mycoauthor}

\vspace{1cm}
\textsf{\mycourse}

\vspace{1cm}
\textsf{\mydate}\\ %%Date - better you write it yourself.

\vspace{1cm}
\textsf{Docent:\\ % meervoud maken door middel van 
Prof. Dr..... \\
}

\vspace{1cm}
\textsf{Lessius Mechelen}

\textsf{Schakelprogramma Industrële Wetenschappen}
\end{flushright}

%Fill up the rest off the document
\vfill
%Add horizontal line
\hrule 
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

I am very pleased with the result. There is however one small thing that bothers me.
[image: Example]

In the TikZ picture, I would like to add a bit more space (1 cm) between the logo and the text (Departement Industriële Wetenschappen) written next to it.

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: can't you just simply xshift=1cm the \node that contains \includegraphics?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\node [name=colourbar,
anchor=base,
fill=blue!40,
minimum width=\paperwidth,
minimum height=1cm] at (midpoint){};

\node [
fill=blue!40,
text = white,
xshift=1cm] at (midpoint){\Large{\textsf{Departement Industriële Wetenschappen}}};
```

You can't use `xshift=1cm` directly because the rectangle is also moved.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `\hspace{1cm}` before `\Large` - it's not so beautiful but works.

Comment: Thanx, however I prefer Altermundus his answer. It has more flexibility to it.