# How to get a colored box as the header?

Tags: color, header-footer

I want to produce this particular template in LaTeX. With no page numbering, and rectangles in colours in a a4paper.

[image: sample made with Word]

Comment: Should "Natural Sciences" be placed at the top of every page (of a particular chapter)?

Comment: I think this question is too localised. "How to create this exact layout" is not a good question for the Q&A format. Perhaps rephrase the question to ask about one specific thing you're having trouble doing. What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes, at the top of every different chapter.

Comment: I need this templates for print first, then in this templates print the document... So i want to produce 4 templates like this but in different colours and whit different title.

Comment: @Seamus I disagree. It can serve as a good example for future visitors. I think one compare it to questions like "how can I draw ... with tikz?". The OP has a problem and is looking for an answer. The question is clearly formulated and the solution is probably a general solution. (That said, I don't know how to do this in LaTeX.)

Comment: @Patrick: This question shows no effort whatsoever. At least getting rid of page numbers is [trivial](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=latex+no+page+numbers) (to find out about), even for beginners. Finding out about headers isn't too hard, either. The colored box is trickier; asking about that would be a specific and valid question. The way it is now, it smells too much like "please do the work for me" if you're asking me. Thinking about tex.sx as a resource for other users, it's pretty unlikely other users will benefit a lot from this question, unless they're searching for "this particular template" ...

Comment: @Seamus you're right of course with the little effort. That's a case for a downvote. But I still believe that generating a colored header is not too localized and valuable for future users.

Comment: Have a look at [Title page using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9808/title-page-using-tikz) which should also work for general headers. Just put the `tikzpicture` environment in the header.

Comment: No page numbering trivial: agree. Colored box trivial: agree. But this color box in header is not trivial for me, and that is the question, and I dont want "anyone do the work for me", maybe my english is poor (Im Chilean Math&Stat teacher at University) sorry for that but this Q&A format page is the best way to question for that... And I love this page (Is my Homepage in Safari!!).

Comment: @hsigrist: Thanks for your feedback. Sorry if we were being a bit harsh. Here's what I would suggest (even though there's an answer already): Edit your question and include the code for a document without page numbers and with a colored box in the _body_ (-> this is what you've got, à la "show your work"). Reformulate your question (including the title) to something like "How to get a colored box as the header?" or "Colored box as page header".

Comment: @Patrick If the question were rephrased to "How do I create a coloured header, then I think it would be a great, focused, answerable, useful question. How about it, @hsigrist?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Eventhough this question does not show a large amount of effort on your part, you can remove page numbering with `\thispagestyle{empty}`. To draw the box you desire at the top of the page, you can use [TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\particulartemplate#1{
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
      node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=2cm, draw, rectangle, fill=blue!20, anchor=north west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.north west)$) {\Large\bfseries \quad #1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter one}
    \particulartemplate{NATURAL SCIENCES}
    \lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

This will make every page on which you invoke `\particulartemplate{Text for box}` to be layed out according to your particular template. The example code provided will look like this:

[image: page with box typeset at top]

It should be relatively straightforward to modify this code to be a little more flexible. (As in, take the color as an argument, whether or not there should be a border, how the text should be justified, etc.)

Comment: I use texlive2011, compile this code under `PDFTeXify` two times, then get the image. But when I compile it under `XeLaTeX` two times, the "NATURAL SCIENCES" is in the top of the box. Sometimes, `XeLaTeX` makes a problem.

Comment: You can make this appear on every page with `usepackage{atbegshi}`  and `\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{\raisebox{-\height}{\particulartemplate{Natural sciences}}}}`