# Output TeX into a PDF template

Tags: graphics, letterhead

I'm writing a cover letter that I want to have on university letterhead, which I have a full-sized electronic copy of (in PDF as well as JPG). Is there an easy way to make TeX do this?

Comment: `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package?

Comment: If the letterhead is a full sized page you could use the `overlay` option with `tikz` to imbed the page with letterhead as a background image.

Comment: I recently used the [wallpaper package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper) for this job.

Comment: `\tikz[overlay, remember picture]\node[opacity=0.8](current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{letterhead.pdf}};`

Comment: @Daniel: your comment is worth converting to an answer.

Comment: @Alex: you too.  Can you give a code snippet as an answer?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Ok, done.

Comment: See also [Creating letters with zero-margin colored headers, in addition to the regular letterhead](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43983/3083).

Answer (score 8):

I recommended to use [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) for such things. If `template.pdf` is the cover letter and `mydocument.pdf` is the (may be LaTeX generated) own document, you can can "stamp" it with the template:

```
pdftk mydocument.pdf background cover.pdf output mydocumentwithcover.pdf
```

`background` is transparent "stamping", but `stamp` is a foreground stamping. If you want to stamp only the first page, create the `template.pdf` with an additinal empty page and use `multistamp`/`multibackground` instead of `stamp`/`background` in `pdftk`.

Comment: ... Care to explain how one would use pdftk for this? Besides, the OP specifically wants a TeX way to do it.

Comment: I agree with the request for a code snippet but not with downvote. Pdftk is a good answer to the question.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Besides the fact that voting is anonymous, `pdftk` seems to be a *great* answer to *many* questions, but without any real explanation per execution.  I'm glad to see a real use case, however. :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred: I think we agree.  `pdftk` is a good basis for an answer and at the time of your comment the answer was incomplete.  Personally, I would not downvote for that (and I'm not saying that you downvoted or that if you did it was for that reason); I would just withhold my upvote until the answer was improved.  I see that whoever did downvote has rescinded it, which seems fair.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the solution using the [wallpaper](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
% adjust margins to fit your letterhead
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=7cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
% embed pdf of letterhead as background image
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\ULCornerWallPaper{1}{empty-letter.pdf}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

Your text goes here \dots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The comments have already mentioned a number of specialized packages for this, including [`eso-pic`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/eso-pic/) and [`wallpaper`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper/). However, an image that shall be put behind the text usually has to be *dimmed* somewhat, so that the text is still readable. For this reason, I would use TikZ, which offers you an easy way to alter the opacity of the included material by its  `opacity=` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only needed for example text, can be removed in real application

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\node[opacity=0.5, anchor=center] at (current page){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}};%
}

\begin{document}

  \lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OP is asking about text on letterhead, which wouldn't normally need to be dimmed.  But this is a good solution for simulating watermarked paper.