# How can I add a background to every page except the first?

Tags: xetex, backgrounds, watermark

I want to make a company letterhead in LaTeX (example output [here](http://media.stochastictechnologies.com/files/sample-letterhead.pdf)), and I did it using `fancyhdr` and absolute positioning, which, while horrible, worked fine so far.

I must have updated XeLaTeX, because now every page after the second is broken. It used to give me warnings about badboxes, but everything worked fine. I think the badboxes were because the "background" image was really in the foreground, and the text was just forcefully positioned over it.

What I want to do is:

1. Create a title page with `\maketitle` that doesn't include a background image.
2. Include a background image on every other page.
3. Create a "back cover" page (using `\makeback`) that doesn't include the background image.

I tried the `wallpaper` package, but it can only set a wallpaper on every page. I tried the `xwatermark` package, but it complains about something called `undefined name grey!55`, which I have no idea about. How can I accomplish what I need?

Comment: The "`undefined name grey!55`" seems to be some misuse of the color packages. "grey!55" is a valid `xcolor` color definition, but maybe an incompatible color package is loaded as well.

Comment: Hmm, I don't use it anywhere, I don't know about the other packages... I'll have a look, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you start your document with the title on page 1, the following is enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\title{foobar}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{}{\includegraphics{backgroundimage.pdf}}}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

I don't know about the \makeback macro, so I can't tell you anything about that.

Comment: Hmm, that almost works, but only adds it on odd pages (predictably). The \makeback macro also just needs a way to remove it, as it's the last page and won't need anything else.

Comment: I used Jubobs' solution for the \ifthenelse and it works perfectly, thank you! It does include a small blank margin to the left, though, do you know how I might remove that so the graphic is flush to the left?

Comment: @StavrosKorokithakis: Change the line `\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{}{\includegraphics{backgroundimage.pdf}}}` to `\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\ifthenelse{\value{page}<2}{}{\includegraphics{backgroundimage.pdf}}}` for it to work.

Comment: That's what I did and it worked well, thanks. I do get a ~2mm margin at bottom that doesn't go away, but I don't think there's  much to do about that.

Comment: By the way, I removed the blank left margin by putting the entire command on one line (having it on multiple lines was what caused it).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend another kind of solution. Use the background as a separate pdf and use [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to "stamp" the pdf generated with TeX. With the multistamp option, you should use a two page pdf as option, where the first page is empty and the second contains your background. The multistamp option was introduced with pdftk 1.44 (AFAIK) and some linux distributions have the older version 1.41 included.

Comment: That will only stamp two pages, though. I want every page past the first one to be stamped with the same background. The solutions posted above work fine, though.

Comment: no, this stamp all pages

Comment: all pages after the last page of the "stamp pdf" will be stamped with the last page of the "stamp pdf"

Comment: see my other answer to a similiar problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91243/output-tex-into-a-pdf-template/110146#110146