# How change the position of background and rotate it?

Tags: formatting, positioning

I used [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104057/how-can-i-add-a-background-to-every-page-except-the-first/452418#452418) to set an image as background. But it is at the bottom of the page. 
My question is
how can I change the position of the image and rotate it about 45 degrees?
I want to put it at the center of the page.

Answer (score 2):

For more control, I use everypage and tikz (or tikzpagenodes).  Everypage runs before the page is shipped out, so it will be in the background without needing layers.

Don't forget to run it twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{everypage}

\AddEverypageHook{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[rotate=45, inner sep=0pt, opacity=.5] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\usepackage{lipsum}%MWE only
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```