# Including an image as an address in a letter

Tags: graphics, positioning, letters

I'm a beginner at LaTeX and I want to write a letter where I can also include an image in the header and an image that represents the address. I found in tex.stackexchange how to include the image in the header, but I couldn't include an image as an adress and couldn't find how anywhere. Could you please help me? Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{headheight = 1.2in}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=0.7in, keepaspectratio=true]{UCA_logo.jpg}}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=0.7in, keepaspectratio=true]{UCA_logo.jpg}}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\date{5 mars 2015}
\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{Lettre à tout lecteur\\ qu'il soit lecteur ou\\ non-lecteur en bonne santé}
        \opening{Dear Some Name,}
        \blindtext
\closing{Cordialement, (formule de politesse)}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Here's what I get. I also showed where I'd like to have my second image, which is in the address position (The date will of course go down a bit).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abuse  `\date` command:

```
\date{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}\\5 mars 2015}
```

Your code:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{headheight = 1.2in}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=0.7in, keepaspectratio=true]{logo}}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=0.7in, keepaspectratio=true]{logo}}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\date{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}\\5 mars 2015}
\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{Lettre à tout lecteur\\ qu'il soit lecteur ou\\ non-lecteur en bonne santé}
        \opening{Dear Some Name,}
        \blindtext
\closing{Cordialement, (formule de politesse)}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really couldn't imagine I could abuse the `\date` command like that!

Comment: @Scientifica Glad it was helpful. You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

you can add

```
\hfill\includegraphics[height=0.7in, keepaspectratio=true]{myfoto}\par
```

or

```
\hfill\includegraphics[height=0.7in, keepaspectratio=true]{myfoto}\\
```

just befor

```
\opening{Dear Some Name,}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What you suggested worked! I looked for \hfill description but I couldn't understand how did it make the image there. Could you please explain to me?

Answer (score 1):

See [using a PDF image in the background of the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43989/3083) as one possible solution. I suggest it in particular if you have multiple graphical elements that need to be aligned. If you need just one image in the top right the other suggestions in that thread could work well, too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried using what you said, using `\documentclass{dinbrief}` but I got the error: "! LaTeX Error: Command \up already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual." What I did is changing the class and inserting the code you put from line 5 to line 15 into my code putting it just after `\date{5 mars 2015}`. Could you please tell me what's wrong?