# fancy chapter title page

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

How can I have a chapter title page like the following?

Note that, I'm using `book` document class

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you could show what you have tried so far, and then let us know which particular part is causing you problems :) Have a look at [How to get a colored box as the header?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33305) for a possible starting point...

Comment: I exactly want the above figure, except `table of contents` part

Comment: Please provide and [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It will be fun and challenging at the same time for many solvers here to answer your question but you can help them get started by providing a MWE. Providing one also shows that you are willing to contribute more to the learning effort here in the TeX-Sx community. :)

Comment: In addition to the link suggested by @cmhughes, check out [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78848/22413].  Doesn't do quite what you want, but it's close.

Comment: [Just do it for me](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2763/5764)...

Comment: @smh I looked at your profile and saw that most of your questions are do-it-for-me questions. I encourage you to post the the minimal code that you have come up with so far.

Comment: @hpesoj626 I don't know where to begin. If I knew the answer, they will not ever be asked!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is a good practice to show that you have done your own part to solve your problem before trying to ask. That way, you will appreciate more what is happening in the solution that you are provided.

I would have to admit thought that this figure requires a lot if you are just beginning in `LaTeX`. The usual `book` class would have sufficed for many beginners like me.

I hope this answer will help you put up your own MWE. Then we will see from there. Be patient since what you are asking for is not trivial. There are some considerations here.

If `memoir` is an option, then I advise you to read: [**Mini table of contents inside TikZ node on chapter start page**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78835/mini-table-of-contents-inside-tikz-node-on-chapter-start-page/78848#78848)

If you are using others (may not work for all, I haven't tried), then you have to use some [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) magic.

You can combine use `titlesec` and use the `tikz` technique used in [**How to get a colored box as the header?**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33305/how-to-get-a-colored-box-as-the-header) and perhaps some [`textpos`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) solution.

I have taken the following `tikz` code from [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78835/mini-table-of-contents-inside-tikz-node-on-chapter-start-page/78848#78848).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
      node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=2cm, draw, rectangle, fill=blue!20, anchor=north west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.north west)$) {\Large\bfseries \quad #1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

But I would trim it down to something that you will need for your background like so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
      node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=2cm, rectangle, fill=cyan, anchor=north west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.north west)$) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

You will need the `cyan`-like color at the bottom of the page so we will further modify it like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
      node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=2.5in, rectangle, fill=cyan, anchor=north west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.north west)$) {};
    \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
      node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=1in, rectangle, fill=cyan!50, anchor=north west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.south west)$) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Then you could use this in combination with `titlesec` to have something in my preamble like

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalsize}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
          node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=5cm, rectangle, fill=cyan, anchor=north west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.north west)$) {};
    \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
          node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=0.8in, rectangle, fill=cyan!50, anchor=south west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.south west)$) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
}{-1.75in}{}[\vspace*{1in}]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Background}
\end{document}
```

You can see the specifications for the `\titleformat{<>}[<>]{<>}{<>}{<>}{<>}[<>]` starting from `page 3` of the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) manual.

**The Chapter title looks small**

And we want to remove the page number at the bottom in the chapter page. So we can also put `\pagestyle{empty}` somewhere. We can change the format as follows:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\color{white}}{% Changed \normalfont
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
     \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
           node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=5cm, rectangle, fill=cyan, anchor=north west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.north west)$) {};
     \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
           node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=0.8in, rectangle, fill=cyan!50, anchor=south west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.south west)$) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
}{-1.5in}{}[\vspace*{1in}]
```

**Some Final Touches**

And we then finally added `\chaptername` and the `\thechapter` so that the chapter and the chapter number will appear. You can use [`textpos`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) so that you can manually position them.

**Finally, an MWE that you can work on**

It is a terrible hack, but it works for me in many instances. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{calc}

\DeclareFixedFont{\chapternumberfont}{T1}{ppl}{}{}{1.5in}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\color{white}}{
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
              node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=5cm, rectangle, fill=cyan, anchor=north west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.north west)$) {
                \begin{textblock*}{5in}(\dimexpr\x2-4.5in,\dimexpr0.25\headheight-1in)
                    \tikz \node [white,text width=2in, align=right, font=\sffamily] {{\normalsize DIGITAL MEDIA PRIMER}\\[12pt] \raisebox{50pt}{{\large \chaptertitlename}} \raisebox{-12pt}{\chapternumberfont \thechapter}};
                \end{textblock*}
              };
        \path let \p1 = (current page.west), \p2 = (current page.east) in
              node[minimum width=\x2-\x1, minimum height=0.8in, rectangle, fill=cyan!50, anchor=south west, align=left, text width=\x2-\x1] at ($(current page.south west)$) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
}{-1.75in}{}[\vspace*{1in}]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Background}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

If you have some more time, you can combine the procedure I have outline here with the answer of **Peter Grill** in [**Using fancyhdr to create an image based header and footer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42073/using-fancyhdr-to-create-an-image-based-header-and-footera)