# fancy chapter title page for entire document

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, formatting, chapters

How to enable [this style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89208/fancy-chapter-title-page) as well for TOC and bibliographypage ?

Note that, I'm using `scrreprt` document class

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation of the code used in the answer linked in the question; with this new code the `textpos` package is no longer required; using `\titleformat` with the `numberless` key, one can also get the desired formatting for unnumbered chapters (`\tableofcontents`, for example):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\DeclareFixedFont{\chapternumberfont}{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}{1.5in}

\newcommand\brectangles{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\fill[cyan] 
  (current page.north west) rectangle ( $ (current page.north east) + (0,-7cm) $);
\fill[cyan!30] 
  (current page.south west) rectangle ( $ (current page.south east) + (0,3cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\color{white}}
  {\thispagestyle{empty}\brectangles}
  {-1.75in}
  {%
  \vskip-4ex\filleft {\small\MakeUppercase{Digital Media Primer}}\\[2ex]
  \parbox[b]{.65\linewidth}{#1}%
  \raisebox{0.8in}{\parbox{.15\linewidth}{\large\chaptertitlename}}%
  \parbox[b]{.2\linewidth}{\chapternumberfont\thechapter}%
  }
  [\vspace*{1in}]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\color{white}}
  {\thispagestyle{empty}\brectangles} 
  {-1in}
  {\parbox[b]{.65\linewidth}{#1}}
  [\vspace*{1in}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Background}

\end{document}
```

Am image of the resulting document showing the desired formatting for both numbered and unnumbered chapters:

[image]

Feel free to make the adjustments that you consider best suit your needs.