# Creating Page Border for Single Page only

Tags: margins, framed

I am digitizing a book and there is  only a single page which has page border as shown in the attached image.
How can I create border to a single page? Is there a library where I can choose a border from?

[image: Example of page with a border]

Comment: Have a look at [Use TikZ to draw frontpage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/use-tikz-to-draw-frontpage) and [Page border coloured](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18222/page-border-coloured). [PGF/TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) allows for a large number of path decorations which can be used here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make a title page like this using TikZ decorations e.g. inside a `titlepage` environment. TikZ allows for a lot of different decorations and you can even define your own. It also allows for easy use of colors etc.

Example to show the principle:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=1mm,decorate,decoration={snake
        %,segment length=<length>,amplitude=<length>
        }]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1cm,-1cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm) $);
    \draw [line width=1mm,decorate,decoration={zigzag
        %,segment length=<length>,amplitude=<length>
        }]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (2cm,-2cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-2cm,2cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \huge
    Your title text

    Author

    more text

\end{titlepage}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: This is [31.2, p. 377](https://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) of the pgf-manual 2012.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use the [`fancybox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancybox). Analogous to `\thispagestyle{...}`, it provides `\thisfancyput(<x>,<y>){<LR stuff>}`. Here is a *very* short example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancybox
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancybox
\begin{document}

\thisfancyput(3.25in,-4.5in){%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1in}\fancyoval(7,9.5)}%
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image: A fancy page]

You can add various components sequentially by using the starred version `*` of `\thisfancyput`.

It is *extremely* limited in its capability with respect to [`tikz`/`pgf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

---

Here is another alternative, using [`pst-node`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node) (from the [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) bundle). Using [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to tap into the "background" of a specific page via `\AddtoShipoutPictureBG*`, you can be creative with any `pstricks`-related code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document} 

\begin{titlepage}
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \begin{pspicture}(\paperwidth,\paperheight)
      \psset{xunit=\the\paperwidth,yunit=\the\paperheight,nodesep=2cm}
      \pnode(1,1){page.northeast}%
      \pnode(0,0){page.southwest}%

      \psframe[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=10pt,linecolor=orange!50]([angle=45]page.southwest)([angle=-135]page.northeast)
    \end{pspicture}
  }
  \centering
  \huge
  Your title text

  Author

  more text
\end{titlepage}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

This does require a `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf` compilation sequence though. [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) provided an advanced colour selection interface, while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides dummy text *Lorem Ipsum* style.

Answer (score 2):

the ["glisterings" column](http://tug.org/members/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101glister.pdf) by peter wilson in tugboat 32:2 (2011) includes instructions for a border using fleurons from the (free) Web-O-Mints font, with [latex support](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/webomints) provided by Maurizio Loreti.  the general approach is to define an "evenfoot" and an "oddfoot" by stringing together appropriately matching fleurons in a `picture` environment and using the `\put` command to move the frame into the desired location. it is placed on the desired page using the standard `\pagestyle` technique.

since this column is in the most recent issue of tugboat, at the moment it is accessible only to tug members, but i will see if i can negotiate an exception.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing would probably be easiest to perform with [Tikz](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). Simply draw a path around the border of the page and decorate it as described in chapter 21 of the manual.

edit: I could have sworn I added a link... Well added it now, as for the example, I think Martin's answer already adresses that, so it would be superfluous to add one here now.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a complete example of how this can be done?

Comment: @whlt3 - there is no link to documentation. Can you please add that, also if there is a working example as said by N.N. it would be great help for novices like me.

Comment: You are missing a hyperlink in "You can find the documentation here", do you? Anyway, please no "here" or "this" links. Use something meaningful as hyperlink name.