# Where can I find examples of decorated borders/margins?

Tags: resources

Are there any readily available examples of decorated borders/margins? I am trying to have some decore running along the edges of page, e.g. Gargoyles/Motif/Some type of mathematical curve/whatever.

Just need some examples to get started and have a choice to pick from.

Comment: Perhaps @Martin Scharrer's answer over here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31135/creating-page-border-for-single-page-only/31143#31143 Might be of some interest as well.

Comment: CTAN offers a list of packages associated with the keyword: _boxed text, frames_: http://www.ctan.org/keyword/boxed

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could take a look to [niceframe](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/niceframe) and [umrand](http://ctan.org/pkg/umrand) (Examples see below)

umrand: in http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/umrand/umrand12.zip is a dvi-file with examples. See below (It's the German description, but it contains a lot of examples).

niceframe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{niceframe}
\usepackage{swrule}% englische Linien
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}


\section{niceframe}

\subsection{niceframe}
\niceframe{\blindtext}

\subsection{artdecoframe}
\artdecoframe{\blindtext}

\subsection{\curlyframe}
\curlyframe{\blindtext}


~\swrule{0.6\textwidth}{1pt}~


\end{document}
```

[image: See attached pdf]

[image]

Comment: There's a new CTAN Package: ghab
The package defines a command \darghab that will typeset its argument in a box with a decorated frame.  The width of the box may be set using an optional argument.

http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ghab
http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ghab

Answer (score 11):

You may want to have a look at [vectorian](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/).