# Is it possible to frame text using a graphic border

Tags: graphics, framed

I've got a document where in a few cases I'm using the `framed` package and a single `\begin{framed} <text> \end{framed}` to visually separate text that is something akin to commentry on the main text. So far it works correctly, but I was wondering if there was any way to make it artistically interesting?

Is there any package that would do something like a `framed` environment, but using a custom graphic for the frame instead of a simple line? I haven't actually chosen a graphic yet so it shouldn't be a problem if it requires a specific format, or if it only comes with a limited preselection of graphic borders.

Comment: You can give a try with `mdframed` and/or `tcolorbox`. I like both of them. Also for frames you can have a look at `pgfornaments` by altermundus (http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html)

Comment: Also look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41159/does-anybody-know-a-good-source-of-free-ornaments-decorations-frames-backgr, and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46406/package-for-certificates

Comment: @HarishKumar the pgfornament package looks like it does exactly what I want. If you move your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To put some thing inside a good looking frame, I suggest to use the `pgfornaments` ([Link](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html))  package from @altermundus. It provides all symbols which one gets from [`psvectorian`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psvectorian) (which can be used only with latex, not with pdflatex). pgfornaments runs like a charm with pdflatex.

While one can find some examples in the site of pgfornaments itself, the following links may also be useful:

[Tex.Sx-1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41159/does-anybody-know-a-good-source-of-free-ornaments-decorations-frames-backgr)

[TeX.Sx-2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46406/package-for-certificates)

For ready reference within TeX.SX, I am reproducing an example from @Altermundus himself:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{fondpaille}
\color{Maroon} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]   
\node[text width=8cm,align=center](Text){%
In visions of the dark night\\
I have dreamed of joy departed-\\
But a waking dream of life and light    Hath left me broken-hearted.\\
\bigskip
Ah! what is not a dream by day\\
To him whose eyes are cast \\
On things around him with a ray \\
Turned back upon the past? \\
\bigskip        
That holy dream- that holy dream,\\
While all the world were chiding,\\
Hath cheered me as a lovely beam\\
A lonely spirit guiding.\\
\bigskip        
What though that light, thro' storm and night,\\
So trembled from afar- \\
What could there be more purely bright \\
In Truth's day-star? \\
\vspace{24pt}
 A Dream  (1827) by Edgar Allan Poe 
} ;
\node[shift={(-1cm,1cm)},anchor=north west](CNW)  at (Text.north west)
               {\pgfornament[width=2cm]{61}};
\node[shift={(1cm,1cm)},anchor=north east](CNE)   at (Text.north east)
               {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{61}}; 
\node[shift={(-1cm,-1cm)},anchor=south west](CSW) at (Text.south west)
               {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{61}}; 
\node[shift={(1cm,-1cm)},anchor=south east](CSE)  at (Text.south east)   
               {\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{61}};  
\pgfornamenthline{CNW}{CNE}{north}{87}
\pgfornamenthline{CSW}{CSE}{south}{87}
\pgfornamentvline{CNW}{CSW}{west}{87}
\pgfornamentvline{CNE}{CSE}{east}{87} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More examples can be found in the pgfornaments site with link given above.