# How to draw a simple but beautiful decorative head-rule?

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, rules, decorations

The picture shown below is the desired simple head-rule, but the rule width should be much thinner like `1pt`.

[image]

Real one:
[image]

So how to use `Tikz` or other packages to draw this kind of line as a `headrule`?

Or alternatively, suppose I have the vector pciture in pdf form, e.g `head-rule.pdf`, how can I include it for use of head-rule?

Comment: Do you insist on TikZ? There is psvectorian: http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/

Comment: there is also `pgfornament` http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46401/3235 but Alain Mathes mentions a license problem in the comments.

Comment: [related](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tug.org%2FTUGboat%2Ftb31-1%2Ftb97inn.pdf&ei=h10VUYnnJ5GJhQfjgIHACA&usg=AFQjCNHALT2ysi3pNOmI0MEd7HgdQeftqg&bvm=bv.42080656,d.ZG4)?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen, it's too stylish `:)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the aforementioned rule using `tikz` with the center dot set to 1 pt. In the updated version, I filled them in and extended them to slightly more than `\textwidth`. You can tweak the number I divided `\textwidth` by in order to shorten or lengthen it. Note that it looks better with both the `\fill` and the `\draw` commands together. Without the latter, the edges are not crisp enough. [Sorry for the delay in updating. I was digging out from a snowstorm.]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (0,0) circle (1pt);
\draw (0.2,0) .. controls (0.2,0.075) and (1,0) .. (\textwidth/2,0);
\fill (0.2,0) .. controls (0.2,0.075) and (1,0) .. (\textwidth/2,0);
\draw (0.2,0) .. controls (0.2,-0.075) and (1,0) .. (\textwidth/2,0);
\fill (0.2,0) .. controls (0.2,-0.075) and (1,0) .. (\textwidth/2,0);
\draw (-0.2,0) .. controls (-0.2,0.075) and (-1,0) .. (-\textwidth/2,0);
\fill (-0.2,0) .. controls (-0.2,0.075) and (-1,0) .. (-\textwidth/2,0);
\draw (-0.2,0) .. controls (-0.2,-0.075) and (-1,0) .. (-\textwidth/2,0);
\fill (-0.2,0) .. controls (-0.2,-0.075) and (-1,0) .. (-\textwidth/2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

To use this with `fancyhdr` just put the above code inside `\chead{}` in your preamble.

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: It's very close to the desired one. Can you make it as long as the `\textwidth`, and fill in with black color?

Comment: Just updated. Sorry for the delay in replying. Had to dig out from a snowstorm.

Comment: that is Great. Could you please show a MWE for use of this line for `headrule`?

Comment: Do you specifically want an MWE that utilizes `fancyhdr` or are you trying to avoid `fancyhdr`? If you're using it, you can just stick the above code inside `\chead{}`.

Comment: It worked, perfect.