# How to typeset an exhibition catalogue

Tags: document-classes, book-design

Perhaps this is too vague, but I have been so impressed with the results I was able to achieve based on a previous question, that I thought I would ask.

Has anyone used TeX to typeset an exhibition catalogue? I'm looking for some base classes to build a nice layout that can alternate pages with large images and small textual captions, with pages of text with small or no images.

This is an old-style example from 1955. Very classic and typography heavy, with separate image plates.
http://www.aucklandartgallery.com/media/166104/cat4.pdf

This is a more modern style and a nice compact design:
http://www.aucklandartgallery.com/media/335251/cat69.pdf

Any suggestions or guidance toward a good approach would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen these related questions: [Package for certificates](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46425) and [Does anybody know a good source of (free) ornaments, decorations, frames, backgrounds etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88093) and [Totally sweet horizontal rules in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76555) ?

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: look into the `geometry` package for adjusting page size, layout and orientation mid-document. those catalogs don't look like too big of a typesetting challenge. you just need some totally sweet horizontal rules.