# Fancy start-of-chapter marks

Tags: text-decorations, posters

I'd like to include some fancy start-of-chapter marks in my poster. I especially like these marks (see pictures below) in a Power Point template. I wonder if there is a convenient way to produce similar marks using LaTeX commands.

[image]

[image]

**Note**: by "LaTeX commands" I don't mean `\includegraphics` and things like that. I might as well just use Power Point. I am wondering if LaTeX could give me similar fancy marks that can be zoomed to arbitrary size with good resolution.

**Also**: I believe these marks are kind of standard, as I have seen them in several places. I am sure I have seen both marks in e-books, and OMG, the first mark appears in this page, right under the TEX header!

[image]

Comment: Actually, `\includegraphics` can used to include vectorial graphics (eps, pdf) which can be zoomed to any size.

Comment: @JavierBezos Good point. I have to admit that my real problem with `\includegraphics` is that I am not willing to pay for high-resolution ornaments just for decorative purposes :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can also use [`pgfornaments`](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html); a little example taken almost verbatim from the package page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[color=red!50!black,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
  \node[minimum size=10cm,inner sep=0pt](vecbox){}; 
  \node[anchor=north west] at (vecbox.north west){\pgfornament[width=2cm]{63}};
  \node[anchor=north east] at (vecbox.north east){\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{63}};
  \node[anchor=south west] at (vecbox.south west){\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{63}};
  \node[anchor=south east] at (vecbox.south east){\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{63}};
  \node[anchor=north] at (vecbox.north){\pgfornament[width=6cm,symmetry=h]{46}};
  \node[anchor=south] at (vecbox.south){\pgfornament[width=6cm]{46}};
  \node[anchor=north,rotate=90] at (vecbox.west){\pgfornament[width=6cm,symmetry=h]{46}};
  \node[anchor=north,rotate=-90] at (vecbox.east){\pgfornament[width=6cm,symmetry=h]{46}};
  \node[inner sep=6pt] (text) at (vecbox.center){\Huge Ornaments};
  \node[anchor=north] at (text.south){\pgfornament[width=5cm]{60}};
  \node[anchor=south] at (text.north){\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=h]{49}};
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And, of course, you can control the attributes (including size) using the options for `\pgfornament`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=h]{49}
\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=h]{49}
\pgfornament[width=10cm]{49}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Processing the following code, you'll get a four page document showing the 89 predefined ornaments:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\newcounter{ornnumb}

\begin{document}

\noindent\loop
\ifnum\value{ornnumb}<89
\stepcounter{ornnumb}%
ornament~\theornnumb: \pgfornament[width=1.5cm]{\theornnumb}\\[1ex]
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using the package for my poster. It's been great after a day's work!

Comment: How do I install pgfornament.sty appropriately?

Comment: @macmadness86 extract the files from the .zip file and place them in the appropriate location under your local TDS tree.

Comment: That answer was too easy! I always forget where the appropriate places are! Using mactex. I know it is somewhere in /usr/local/texlive/2012/. I also know I have to run some kind of cache command. texcache or something similar.

Comment: @macmadness86 You need to run `texhash`; I am not a Mac user, so I don't know the exact details for Mac, but since MacTeX is based in TeX Live, this answer could be useful for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73017/3954 (particularly the third method described there).

Comment: *for completeness, on a unix system*: **pgfornament** must to be in /texmf/tex/latex, **pgflibraryvectorian.code.tex** must to be in /texmf/tex/latex, **pgflibraryam.code.tex**, must to be in /texmf/tex/latex,
the folder **vectorian** must to be in /texmf/tex/generic,
the folder **am** must to be in /texmf/tex/generic, then run sudo *texhash* as Gonzalo Medina noted above.

Answer (score 18):

If you're prepared to use Xe(La)TeX, a number of Opentype fonts have a good selection of fleurons and other ornaments.

Here, for example, is a fragment from one of my visiting cards:

```
\newcommand{\ornament}[1]{%
    \fontspec{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}
    \fontsize{8pt}{10pt}
    \selectfont 
    \XeTeXglyph #1 
    \normalfont}%
...
\ornament{1620}
```

which gets you this:

[image]

I haven't included a list of fonts and/or ornaments, though, as I don't really think this is the place. Perhaps other users will comment or post additional answers.

Answer (score 7):

you may want to have a look at [vectorian](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/) and this disccusion on [decorated borders](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31807/where-i-can-find-examples-of-decorated-borders-margins/31816#31816).

Comment: In my humble opinion, this is not a very sophisticated answer. Like this it should probably a comment. Maybe you can improve on it, show some code and the result, so to say add some "eye candy"?

Comment: Code is available at the given link. It is in French but can just be copied and pasted. I do not see the point of doing this here.

Comment: @pluton: "[A]lthough we value brevity, a great answer should still provide enough information so that even an inexperienced (but diligent and motivated) user can reproduce the solution just by reading the answer, and possibly following some instructions." "the solution should be entered in the text of the answer itself. Attributions to external sources are fine – and encouraged! – but just linking to solutions posted elsewhere outside of the site should be discouraged." -- [Quality Standards for Answers](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/227)

Comment: you could have just indicated the links :) Honestly, I disagree with these rules. In my answer (that should probably be a comment), I do not bring anything new. The pgfornament package is itself inspired by vectorian. Centralizing information is somehow problematic I guess on the net even though a limitation occurs when linked sites die. For original and sophisticated answers, I would agree.

Comment: @pluton: Don't forget to use the `@username` notation when you're responding to someone's comment -- I just found your response because I checked back coincidentally. // I come from the humanities, I like to quote stuff `;)` // If you disagree with the rules, feel free to discuss them on [meta] or in [chat]. However, I have a feeling these quality standards are so fundamental that you'll have a hard time getting them changed ...

Comment: @doncherry: yes, I usually try to use this `@username` notation but sometimes, it does not work and I am not sure why.

Comment: Its behavior is something like this: The creator of a post will always be notified of comments on the post. If no other user has commented on the post yet, `@postcreator` will automatically be removed. If other users have already commented on the post, it won't be removed to give you an option to make clear who you're addressing with your comment -- in terms of notifications, the `@postcreator` is never necessary, however. (Just like you should be notified of this comment without me putting your name in it.) In all other cases, the `@username` should work.