# How do I recreate these ornaments?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was referring the `psvectorian` package for attractive borders and styles. I came across this:

[image]

I badly know how to do this.The documentation doesn't show much on how to achieve this.Please help me.

Comment: Could you please post an external source, where you got this document from.

Comment: http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/psvectorian.pdf @HenriMenke

Comment: The source for that document is available [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-vectorian/psvectorian.tex).

Comment: You didn't choose a very informative title, to say the least. Thankfully, @marczellm found a better one. In the future, try to concisely describe the issue in the question title. You'll stand a better chance of attracting people who already know a good answer.

Comment: I will take care of that @Jubobs

Comment: @PaulGessler the code doesn't compile, it has lots of errors....

Comment: @subhamsoni The packages that begin with `ps` are usually based on PSTricks. So you cannot compile it with pdflatex, you need `latex -> dvips ->ps2pdf`.

Comment: Do you know http://altermundus.com/pages/downloads/packages/pgfornament/ornaments.pdf ?

Comment: Yes. I have that pdf as well but I want to do this , its awesome.. @PaulGaborit

Comment: Related: [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29805/5764)

Comment: I would think you could follow the steps/advice in [Fancy start-of-chapter marks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75434/5764), perhaps making this a duplicate...

Comment: the source of the documentation is available on CTAN (http://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-vectorian) and also on your local TeX installation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have defined two macros:

```
%% A macro with two arguments to change ornaments and colors easily
%% Syntax -- \sectionlinetwo{<color>}{<ornament>}
\newcommand{\sectionline}[2]{%
  \nointerlineskip \vspace{.5\baselineskip}\hspace{\fill}
  {\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{1.2ex}
    {\pgfornament[color = #1]{#2}
    }}%
    \hspace{\fill}
    \par\nointerlineskip \vspace{.5\baselineskip}
  }
```

Refer: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76555/11232). This will draw the ornaments between the paragraphs. The other one is versatile and can be used elsewhere:

```
\newcommand\myornament[3][black]{%
    \resizebox{#2}{!}{\pgfornament[color = #1]{#3}%
}%
}
%% syntax 
%% \myornament[<color|optional, default is black>]{<width>}{<ornament number>}
```

Now the full code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament} %%  http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}

%% A macro with two arguments to change ornaments and colors easily
%% Syntax -- \sectionlinetwo{<color>}{<ornament>}
\newcommand{\sectionline}[2]{%
  \nointerlineskip \vspace{.5\baselineskip}\hspace{\fill}
  {\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{1.2ex}
    {\pgfornament[color = #1]{#2}
    }}%
    \hspace{\fill}
    \par\nointerlineskip \vspace{.5\baselineskip}
  }
\newcommand\myornament[3][black]{%
\resizebox{#2}{!}{\pgfornament[color = #1]{#3}%
    }%
    }

\begin{document}
\noindent \myornament[DarkRed]{0.3\linewidth}{72} \hfill%
\LARGE Motifs d'ornaments \hfill%
\myornament[DarkRed]{0.3\linewidth}{73}%
\par
\begin{center}
  \myornament[DarkRed]{0.7\linewidth}{85}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]

\sectionline{magenta}{84}

\lipsum[3]

\sectionline{DarkGreen}{88}
\par\noindent
\myornament[DarkRed]{\linewidth}{60}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do you know which number represents which ornaments? I peeked in to the `pgfornament`s [manual](http://altermundus.com/pages/downloads/packages/pgfornament/ornaments.pdf) (pages 17-20).  You can download `pgfornament` [from here.](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html)

`pgfornament` is compatible with pdflatex.