# Huge ornament chapter numbering

Tags: chapters, fancyhdr

Well, I'm using a such a code bellow, basically I would like to add ornaments to the numbering of this chapter... Any ideas, examples please? thanks a lot[image]

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
  \makeatletter
       \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
        \vspace*{50\p@}%
        {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        %\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        %    \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        %    \par\nobreak
        %    \vskip 20\p@
        %\fi
     \interlinepenalty\@M
          \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
      \vskip 40\p@
       }}
      \makeatother
```

---

```
% Datei fancyheaders.tex
% Kopf- und Fu�zeile mit Paket fancyhdr
% Paket muss extra installiert werden


\usepackage{fancyhdr}   % Paket laden
 \pagestyle{fancy}  % bereitgestelltes Layout 'fancy' laden
 % Am Anfang jeder neuen \section wird deren Name in die linke Kopfzeile         geschrieben, dazu neuen command definieren
 %\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ #1}{}}
 % Am Anfang jeder neuen \subsection wird deren Name in die rechte Kopfzeile  geschrieben, dazu neuen command definieren
 %\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
  %  Die so erzeugten Inhalte stehen jetzt mit den Befehlen
   % \leftmark und \rightmark zur Verf�gung und k�nnen wie im folgenden eingesetzt werden:
    % \lhead[\rightmark]{\rightmark}

  %\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
   \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsl{\thesection\ #1}}}

   %%\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\textsl{\chaptername\  \thechapter\ : #1}}{}}
   %\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

    \makeatletter
       \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
        \vspace*{50\p@}%
       {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
  %\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  %    \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
  %    \par\nobreak
  %    \vskip 20\p@
  %\fi
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
  \vskip 40\p@
}}
 \makeatother





\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\chapnumfont}{%     % define font for chapter number
 \usefont{T1}{pnc}{b}{n}%      % choose New Chancery, bold, normal shape
 \fontsize{100}{100}%          % font size 100pt, baselineskip 100pt
 \selectfont%                  % activate font
  }
  \colorlet{chapnumcol}{gray!100}  % color for chapter number

     \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\filleft\bfseries}
  {\filleft\chapnumfont\textcolor{chapnumcol}{\thechapter}}
  {-24pt}
  {\Huge}


  \fancyhead{}
     %\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
      \fancyhead[L]{}
      \fancyhead[R]{}%{\rightmark}
     \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
     \fancyfoot[C]{}%{\leftmark}
      \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
     \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}



      % Style "plain" berschreiben, das bei 
     %\chapter{...} mit aktiviert wird
   \fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \lhead{}
     \chead{}
      \rhead{}
     \lfoot{}
     \cfoot{}
   \rfoot{\thepage}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
       \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}}
```

Comment: The code snippet you just posted has nothing to do with the image. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What kind of ornaments do you want? Can you please add a complete minimal document producing the output you show in the image?

Comment: have you seen [How do I recreate these ornaments?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159471) ?

Comment: Please post your *code* as @GonzaloMedina requested.

Comment: Tip: You can edit your question. Don't post further information as an answer unless it really is an answer to your question. Instead, edit your question and add the information there.

Answer (score 10):

Below I present several options produced with the help of the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package.

Two simple alternatives . The first one simply draws a frame around the number; the second one uses a colored background with shades (requires TikZ):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\let\cleardoublepage\relax     % just for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedleft}
  {\fbox{\makebox[3cm][r]{\fontsize{100}{130}\color{gray}\selectfont\thechapter}}}
  {20pt}
  {\Huge}
\chapter{Test chapter}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedleft}
  {\tikz\node[inner xsep=0pt,top color=gray!10,bottom color=gray!70,text width=3.5cm,align=right] 
    {{\fontsize{100}{130}\color{gray}\selectfont\thechapter}};%
  }
  {20pt}
  {\Huge}
\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another one, adding a simple rule to the right:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\let\cleardoublepage\relax     % just for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedleft}
  {{\fontsize{100}{130}\color{gray}\selectfont\thechapter\rlap{\vrule width 2pt height 100pt}}}
  {20pt}
  {\Huge}
\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some more elaborate decorations using [`pgfornament`](http://www.altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\let\cleardoublepage\relax     % just for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedleft}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=3cm,align=center] (chapnum)
    {\fontsize{100}{130}\color{gray}\selectfont\thechapter};%
  \node[shift={(-1cm,1cm)},anchor=north west](CNW)
    at (chapnum.north west) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm]{61}};
  \node[shift={(1cm,1cm)},anchor=north east](CNE)
    at (chapnum.north east) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=v]{61}};
  \node[shift={(-1cm,-1cm)},anchor=south west](CSW)
    at (chapnum.south west) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
  \node[shift={(1cm,-1cm)},anchor=south east](CSE)
    at (chapnum.south east) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  {20pt}
  {\Huge}
\chapter{Test chapter}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedleft}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=3cm,align=center] (chapnum)
    {\fontsize{100}{130}\color{gray}\selectfont\thechapter};%
  \node[shift={(-1cm,10pt)},anchor=north west](CNW)
    at (chapnum.north west) {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{7}};
  \node[shift={(1cm,10pt)},anchor=north east](CNE)
    at (chapnum.north east) {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=v]{7}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  {20pt}
  {\Huge}
\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And two more examples, this time using the Web-O-Mints fonts:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*\wb[2]{%
  \fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}

\begin{document}

\let\cleardoublepage\relax     % just for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedleft}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=3cm,align=center] (chapnum)
    {\fontsize{100}{130}\color{gray}\selectfont\thechapter};%
  \node[shift={(-1cm,1cm)},anchor=north west](CNW)
    at (chapnum.north west) {\wb{20}{24}I};
  \node[shift={(1cm,1cm)},anchor=north east](CNE)
    at (chapnum.north east) {\wb{20}{24}J};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  {20pt}
  {\Huge}
\chapter{Test chapter}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedleft}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=3cm,align=center] (chapnum)
    {\fontsize{100}{130}\color{gray}\selectfont\thechapter};%
  \node[shift={(-1cm,1cm)},anchor=north west](CNW)
    at (chapnum.north west) {\wb{40}{48}A};
  \node[shift={(1cm,1cm)},anchor=north east](CNE)
    at (chapnum.north east) {\wb{40}{48}B};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  {20pt}
  {\Huge}
\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, ok sounds simple.. but how do I solve :

Comment: Error file pgfornament.sty not found ?

Comment: @user35815 you need to install it. I provided the link to where you can find it.

Comment: I'm quite new here, so can you send here link here and give some instructions about how to install .sty files?

Comment: @user35815 The link is already included in the answer. You just need to click on it. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files for installing it.

Comment: OK it works :), thank you for your help and time.

Comment: @user35815 You're welcome! Don't forget that after a sensible wait you can accept the answer that you consider best solved your problem, by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).