# Typesetting ornamental cards?

Tags: poetry, cards

I'm currently trying to print out some small poems onto card, and I stumbled onto the article ["Typesetting modern & contemporary poetry with LaTeX"](http://www.ntg.nl/maps/24/06.pdf).

Some of the examples in there are truly beautiful.

Does anybody know if the source for this, or anything else is available in the public domain?

Or how else would you create LaTeX cards with ornamental borders and ligatures like that?

Comment: The author of this article gives some hints of the process. The ornamental border is explained in the first page, more in [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31807/where-i-can-find-examples-of-decorated-borders-margins). The ligatures are part of the used font.

Comment: If you're not looking for anything specific try searching this site for "ornament" and "vignette" and you'll see lots of examples.

Comment: `pgfornament` might be what you are after. The manual gives several examples. http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html

Comment: The use of ligatures etc. described there is perfectly possible and there are some packages available which already do this for you. However, doing it for an arbitrary font which currently lacks (publicly available) support for fancy ligatures etc. is a little involved. If you don't know how to do it and don't want to spend the time learning, you have two choices: (1) get somebody else to or (2) use `fontspec` with XeLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX) and pick opentype fonts which are are well-designed in terms of feature-support.

Answer (score 2):

For the first example the author gives some hints.

Beside this here a trial to give general advices as summary of comments:

- Ornamental borders are shown in [Where can I find examples of decorated borders/margins?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31807/where-can-i-find-examples-of-decorated-borders-margins)
- There is the nice package [`pgfornament`](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/) by Altermundus, meanwhile better known as [Alain Matthes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144/). A search for [posts containing 'pgfornaments'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=pgfornaments) shows some great examples of usage.
- TikZ contains a library `decorations`. For this an own tag does exist here, so you can go through all questions by clicking on the following text: [decorations](/questions/tagged/decorations).
- You can also search all [questions containing 'ornaments'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=ornaments+is%3Aquestion).
- Especially one question could perhaps tell you all, what your interested in: [Does anybody know a good source of (free) ornaments, decorations, frames, backgrounds etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41159/does-anybody-know-a-good-source-of-free-ornaments-decorations-frames-backgr)