# Fancy Styled Borders in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How to draw attractive Borders in LaTeX. A Sample image like this:
[image]

Comment: You might want to have a look at [pgfornaments](http://altermundus.com/pages/downloads/packages/pgfornament/ornaments.pdf).

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31813/14757

Comment: Any research effort?

Comment: Also may be useful:[Does anybody know a good source of (free) ornaments, decorations, frames, backgrounds etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88093)

Comment: Is the question: how can existing ornaments be used to achieve this effect? Or is it: how can *new* ornaments like this be drawn? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41159/does-anybody-know-a-good-source-of-free-ornaments-decorations-frames-backgr, pgfornaments and the link Sigur posted answer the first question. But the second would be different, although Werner's comment would obviously still stand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Remarks

I traced the bitmap provided using [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) and exported the vector paths to TikZ using the [inkscape2tikz](https://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/) plugin.

Then I adjusted the shift of coordinates, to have a specified origin (here in the top right corner of the ornament). And wrapped everything into a macro `\ornament`.

To place it on the page I used a `tikzpicture` with the `remember picture` and `overlay` options. For more on these options review section 16.13 "Referencing Nodes Outside the Current Pictures" on page 199 of the [TikZ 2.10 manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

## Implementation

You need at least **two passes** of typesetting. See this GitHub Gist for the [`inkscape.tex`](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9035028) file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,blindtext}
\input{inkscape.tex}
\title{Ornaments}
\author{Subham Soni}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[below left] at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east) {\ornament{scale=1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Answer (score 12):

Late solution with Tikz and pgfornament... There are a lot of possibilities to place the ornaments Something in tikz's style ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor} 
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\title{Ornaments}
\author{Alain Matthes}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[below left] at ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east) {\pgfornament[width = .8cm,
             color = MidnightBlue]{15}
\hspace{-6pt}\pgfornament[width = 1.6cm,
             color = MidnightBlue,
             symmetry=h]{15}
\hspace{-8pt}\pgfornament[width = 2.4cm,
                          color = MidnightBlue]{15}};

\node[below right,rotate=270] at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-2cm]current page.north east) {\pgfornament[width = 2.4cm, color = MidnightBlue,symmetry=v]{15}
                           \hspace{-8pt}\pgfornament[width = 1.6cm,
                                        color = MidnightBlue,
                                     symmetry=h,symmetry=v]{15}
                           \hspace{-6pt}\pgfornament[width = 0.8cm,
                                                 color = MidnightBlue,
                                                 symmetry=v]{15}
                                                  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[color=Maroon,
                    every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
 \draw[help lines] (-6,-6) grid (6,6);
 \node[minimum size=12cm](vecbox){}; 
 \node[anchor=north west] at (vecbox.north west)
      {\pgfornament[width=5cm]{61}};
 \node[anchor=north east] at (vecbox.north east)
      {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=v]{61}};
 \node[anchor=south west] at (vecbox.south west)
      {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
 \node[anchor=south east] at (vecbox.south east)
      {\pgfornament[width=5cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]