# Frame around a page latex

Tags: floats, framed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating Page Border for Single Page only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31135/creating-page-border-for-single-page-only)

Hello I need to put a double frame around an A4 page in latex. How to do this ? I looked into psframe. Did not quite get it !

Comment: Your are working with `pstricks`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Creating Page Border for Single Page only](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31135/5764)

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for the eso-pic package. One of the given examples shows how to put a frame around a page.