# How to add double line border to a page?

Tags: margins, framed

I'm looking for options to add double line border to a page ; left hand top corner of border is mentioned below (border will be continous for entire page width and height).

[image]

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Creating Page Border for Single Page only](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31135/5764)

Comment: All pages of the document

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[line width=4pt]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (1cm,-1cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm) $);
\draw[line width=1.5pt]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (1.2cm,-1.2cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.2cm,1.2cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-16]
\end{document}
```

Use the starred version of `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` (`\AddToShipoutPictureBG*`) if you want it only for one page and place that code in the wanted page.

Comment: @PawanMude You're welcome. And thank for the Sir :-)