# How to set page borders very basic way

Tags: titles, border

I want to set page borders but is getting confused between various answers and tutorials.

All I want is simple, double-lined page borders (with black color) for my page.
I am also getting confused about the very basic packages you require with miktex for the purpose.

I think that tikz is something you require?

I am beginner to latex and going through various tutorials for title-page designing. I have designed the title page but this border thing is very confusing.

Very basic method for border insertion in the title page, or any other pages?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [How to add double line border to a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232682/134144)

Comment: A simple "remember picture, overlay" Ti*k*Z picture is ok to draw not only that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What titlepage design do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is use `fancybox` and `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\noindent\doublebox{\begin{minipage}[c]%
[\dimexpr\textheight-2\fboxsep-7.5\fboxrule-1pt][c]
{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-7.5\fboxrule-1pt}%
\centering
\leavevmode\vfill
\huge Your title page here
\vfill\leavevmode
\end{minipage}}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]